# Failed assertion: line 55 pos 16: 'configuration.containsKey('provider')': is not true

Tags: flutter, payment

I'm building a payment option but I don't know why I'm getting this error even though I did exactly the same as the instruction. I'm first doing the Gpay. My code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pay/pay.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {

  final _paymentItems = [
    PaymentItem(
      label: 'Total',
      amount: '99.99',
      status: PaymentItemStatus.final_price,
    )
  ];
  void onGooglePayResult(paymentResult) {
    debugPrint(paymentResult.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("App Bar"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            GooglePayButton(
              width: 300,
              paymentConfigurationAsset: 'gpay.json',
              paymentItems: _paymentItems,
              style: GooglePayButtonStyle.black,
              type: GooglePayButtonType.pay,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
              onPaymentResult: onGooglePayResult,
              loadingIndicator: const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and my gpay.json inside assets folder is:

```
{
  "apiVersion": 2,
  "apiVersionMinor": 0,
  "merchantInfo": {
    "merchantName": "Example Merchant"
  },
  "allowedPaymentMethods": [
    {
      "type": "CARD",
      "parameters": {
        "allowedAuthMethods": ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"],
        "allowedCardNetworks": ["AMEX", "DISCOVER", "INTERAC", "JCB", "MASTERCARD", "MIR", "VISA"]
      },
      "tokenizationSpecification": {
        "type": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
        "parameters": {
          "gateway": "example",
          "gatewayMerchantId": "exampleGatewayMerchantId"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "transactionInfo": {
    "totalPriceStatus": "FINAL",
    "totalPrice": "12.34",
    "currencyCode": "USD"
  }
}
```

The error message throws me this:

```
E/flutter ( 3869): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Unhandled Exception: 'package:pay_platform_interface/core/payment_configuration.dart': Failed assertion: line 55 pos 16: 'configuration.containsKey('provider')': is not true., stack trace: #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
E/flutter ( 3869): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
E/flutter ( 3869): #2      new PaymentConfiguration._ (package:pay_platform_interface/core/payment_configuration.dart:55:16)
E/flutter ( 3869): #3      PaymentConfiguration.fromAsset (package:pay_platform_interface/core/payment_configuration.dart:85:33)
E/flutter ( 3869): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3869): #4      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:473:21)
E/flutter ( 3869): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3869): #5      Pay._loadConfigAssets (package:pay/src/pay.dart:45:25)
E/flutter ( 3869): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3869):
```

Please help! I'm new to Flutter so I don't really know what's going on!
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

add this to your gpay.json file
`"provider": "google_pay",`